# Stripe webhook doesn't fire correctly in an ASP.NET web forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have written a c# webhook for my asp.net web forms application, and it is acting very strangely.  I can't get Stripe CLI working, so I am having to debug this thing the hard way.  The weird thing is, it partially works.

Here's the complete code for the handler:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Stripe;
using MMB.Data;

namespace MMB.handlers {
    public class StripeTransactions : IHttpHandler {
        public void ProcessRequest ( HttpContext context ) {
            try {
                var json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
                var stripeEvent=EventUtility.ParseEvent(json);
                if ( stripeEvent.Type == Events.CustomerCreated ) {
                    Customer customer = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.Customer;
                    SiteStatsDB.AddNewCustomer ( );      // Note the fact a new customer was created
                }
                else if ( stripeEvent.Type == Events.PaymentIntentSucceeded ) {
                    SysLog.AddEntry ( "Retrieving PayemtnIntent..." );
                    Stripe.PaymentIntent pmtIntent = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
                    SysLog.AddEntry ( $"StripePaymentIntentID='{pmtIntent.Id}'" );
                    Sale sale = SaleDB.Get($"StripePaymentIntentID='{pmtIntent.Id}'");
                    if ( sale == null )
                        SysLog.AddEntry ( "Unable to locate Sales record" );
                    else
                        SysLog.AddEntry ( "Located Sales record..." );
                    // The following code block only executes if we found a matching Order record AND it hasn't previously been processed as paid.
                    SysLog.AddEntry ( $"Sale record status = WHVerified {sale.WHVerified}" );
                    if ( sale != null && !sale.WHVerified ) {
                        SysLog.AddEntry ( "Successfully retrieved Sale record. Fetching Shipment record..." );
                        Shipment shipment=ShipmentDB.Get($"StripePaymentIntentID='{pmtIntent.Id}'");

                        if ( shipment == null )
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( $"Unable to locate Shipments record : {pmtIntent.Id}" );
                        else
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( "Successfully retrieved Shipments record..." );
                        SysLog.AddEntry ( "Loading Profile record..." );
                        ProfileData profileData = ProfileDataDB.Get($"UserName='{shipment.SoldTo}'");
                        sale.PaidAmount = Convert.ToDouble ( pmtIntent.Amount ) / 100;
                        sale.StripeFee = ( sale.PaidAmount * .971 ) + .3;
                        sale.NetAmount = sale.PaidAmount - sale.StripeFee;
                        SysLog.AddEntry ( "Updating Sales record..." );
                        bool saleVerified=SaleDB.MarkVerified ( sale , out string saleErr);
                        if ( saleVerified )
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( "Successfully updated Sales record..." );
                        else
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( $"Unable to update Sales record - {saleErr}" );
                        Payment pmt = new Payment {
                            UserName = sale.UserName,
                            SaleID=sale.SaleID,
                            PaymentOn=DateTime.Today,
                            PaymentAmount=Convert.ToDecimal(pmtIntent.Amount*.01),
                            StripeReferenceID=pmtIntent.Id,
                            StripeCustomerID=profileData.StripeCustomerID,
                            Comments="CREDIT SALE"
                        };
                        SysLog.AddEntry ( "Saving new Payments record..." );
                        int paymentID = PaymentDB.Add(pmt, out bool pmtSuccess, out string pmtErr);
                        if ( pmtSuccess )
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( "Successfully updated Payments record..." );
                        else
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( $"Unable to create Payments record - {pmtErr}" );
                        shipment.StripeFee = sale.StripeFee;
                        shipment.PaidAmount = sale.PaidAmount;
                        shipment.NetAmount = sale.NetAmount;
                        bool confirmed = ShipmentDB.ConfirmSale (shipment, out string cnfErr);
                        if ( !confirmed )
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( $"Unable to update Shipments record - {cnfErr}" );
                        else
                            SysLog.AddEntry ( "Shipments record updated successfully.  Processing complete." );
                        SiteStatsDB.AddOrder ( shipment.PaidAmount );
                    }
                }
                else if ( stripeEvent.Type == Events.PaymentIntentPaymentFailed ) {
                }
            }
            catch ( StripeException e ) {
                MailSvc.SendTextMail ( "<from_email>", "<to_email>", "Stripe Error", $"Stripe Error:{e.Message}" );
            }
            catch ( Exception ex ) {

            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I instrumented the code with a logger so that I can see where it's failing.
So, when I create a new Customer, that part of the webhook fires and functions just fine.  The issue is with `Events.PaymentIntentSucceeded`.  The first line of code in that block is the logger simply noting that we have hit the correct part of the webhook.  The next line is where I am casting to obtain a Stripe PaymentIntent object from the received Stripe data.  That line of code bombs out, and I know this since the line of code right after it is the logger, noting the ID of the PaymentIntent, and it is never reached.

I get NO error messages when this happens.  I added `catch` blocks specifically for Stripe and a general one, but neither one is hit when the code fails.  My problem is that since I can't get Stripe CLI working, I can't get any further in figuring out what the issue is.

Can anyone give any pointers here on anything else I can do to debug this, keeping in mind I can't use Stripe CLI?

Comment: You don't print out the exception in your catch ( Exception ex ) block. Try printing out the value of ex to see what's wrong.

Comment: I have, and it doesn't even throw an exception of ANY kind.  It's as though it hits that cast to obtain a PaymentIntent object from the Stripe data and falls into some kind of black hole.